# Fastest way to extract tar.gz

Tags: linux, tar, gzip

Is there anyway to extract a tar.gz file faster than `tar -zxvf filenamehere`?

We have large files, and trying to optimize the operation.

Comment: Are you finding that the `$ tar -zxvf` method is IO or CPU bound?

Comment: Believe CPU, how can I check though?

Comment: Not directly related, but 'z' hasn't been required since 2004/tar v1.1.5 http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/#TOCreleases :)

Comment: @Justin You might have to install it, but vmstat will tell you about IO or CPU loading. vmstat  reports  information about processes, memory, paging, block IO, traps, disks and
 cpu activity you can even run it as a continual process, `vmstat 1 100` or every 1 second, for 100 seconds, vmastat outputs. pigz was really helpful, I decompressed 108GB gz file in minutes that was taking over an hour previously.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

[`pigz`](http://zlib.net/pigz/) is a parallel version of gzip. Although it only uses a single thread for decompression, it starts 3 additional threads for reading, writing, and check calculation. Your results may vary but we have seen significant improvement in decompression of some of our datasets. Once you install pigz, the tar file can be extracted with:

```
pigz -dc target.tar.gz | tar xf -
```

Comment: +1. FWIW, you can also write that as `tar -xvf --use-compress-program=pigz filenamehere`. (`-z` amounts to `--use-compress-program=gzip`.) Alternatively, you can even make `gzip` be a symlink to `pigz`, and keep using `-zxvf`.

Comment: @ruakh, I had to put `-xf` after `--use-compress-program=pigz`, or I got an error. For some reason, it was no faster than using `gzip` though.

Comment: For `bzip2` there is `pbzip2` (`p` for parallel). `tar --use-compress-program=pbzip2 -xvf file.tar.bz2`.

Comment: Is there a way to use the `pv` command to show progress, or an equivilant, while also using the `--use-compress-program=pigz` flag? During compression, I can do `gnutar --use-compress-program="pigz | pv" -cf target.tar.gz YourData`, but not sure how to do this during untar/uncompression.

Comment: @StefanLasiewski You can use pigz with pv and tar in this way:  "tar cf - /your/files | pv | pigz > compressed.tgz"

Answer (score 17):

if there are many many many small files in the tar ball, cancel the ‘v’ parameter, try again!

Comment: I never use -v param. Don't know why people need that much noise in console.

Comment: @Eimantas When you untar something that contains many multi-gigabyte files, you will want some indication of progress. :)

Comment: @TimHughes: that's really great to know, please post as a separate answer!

Comment: Michael Hampton if you have a multi-gigabyte files but mixed with a big lists of small files you have a good reason to do not use -v, in my local tests it makes tar very slow specially if you have tar running in a remote server via terminal, what i do is to watch du -s directory so i can watch the directory growing...

Comment: It might be worth using `--checkpoint=NUMBER` (*display progress messages every NUMBERth record*) instead of `-v`.

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini redirect stderr to a file, and then tail the file.

Answer (score 16):

If you want to see progress use something like `pv`. 
Here is an Example:

```
pigz -dc mysql-binary-backup.tar.gz | pv | tar xf -
```

Comment: Nice! You just made my day much more joyful when uncompressing tar archives of hundreds of gigabytes.

Answer (score 1):

With pigz you can speed up extraction and with pv you can view the progress of the extraction. Storing the output of pv to a file allows you to run your command in the background and view the progress at any time.

`pigz -dc mysql-binary-backup.tar.gz | pv --force 2> progress.txt | tar xf - &`

pv typically will not output a visual display if stderr is not a terminal. `--force` ensures that pv is forced to do so. Then we simply redirect stderr using `2>` to progress.txt and pipe the stdout to the tar command. `&` at the end will run the command in the background.

You can see the progress of the extraction by simply running `tail -f progress.txt`